# Get the last 2 moths data from access database table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i have this code for get the last 2 moth of data from access data base to list view in vb.net, but this give me error

this is my code:

```
Public Sub showlistview()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM pay_pretalk _
                                   WHERE sdate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)", con)
    da.Fill(dt)
        Dim myrow As DataRow
        For Each myrow In dt.Rows
            ListView1.Items.Add(myrow.Item(2))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(3))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(4))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(5))
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(6))
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(7))
        Next
End Sub
```

and this is the error:

> IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

how can i do this.

Comment: The title says you are using Access.  You added a MySQL tag (totally different database).  The code uses OleDb which suggests Access, but  AFAIK `DATE_SUB` is a MySQL function.  Once you decide what DB it really is, consider just passing the date as a parameter

Comment: What is dt.Rows.Count?   Does DataTable actually get filled?

Comment: normally i use it my mt code and everything works fine, if i select all data it will appear in the list view , but if i try to get the last 2 moth the code crashes.

Comment: yes I understand but is it actually filling your DataTable?  Do you have Rows in your datatable?  dt.Rows.Count?

Comment: yes i have data , and the data shows in the list view I use " select * from pay_pretalk" everything work good but i cant get the last 2 moth data :(

Comment: So what your saying is the query that you are using is not filling the dataaddapter?  And that is where you are getting the error?

Comment: Trying using `DataAdd` instead of `DATE_SUB`

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: 30 minutes ago: `DATE_SUB is a MySQL function` OleDb/Access is not going to know how to implement that

Comment: im using access data base, and DataAdd not working also, i have the same error for DATA_SUB.

Comment: What I would do is define another variables eDate.  Make it date types and set it to the date that you want.  Then include it within the SQL statement ("SELECT * FROM pay_pretalk WHERE sDate > " + eDate ,con)

Comment: Dim eDate As Date = Date.Now.AddMonths(2)

Answer (score 0):

```
            dim ds as new DataSet();
            dim adapter as new OleDataDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM pay_pretalk                                             

            WHERE sdate > DateAdd("m", -2, Date())", con);
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

.....

Comment: con.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; data source = |datadirectory|\noorapp.accdb;"

this is rge connection string

Comment: and where does your application error?.  I think its a driver issue with access. but still you have not told me where the error is